# Android Canvas.ClipPath

Tags: android, canvas

I wanna clip a circle region, but somehow I got a rectangle, not a circle.
And here is my code:

```
protected boolean drawChild(Canvas canvas, View child, long drawTime) {
                mRevealPath.reset();
                mRevealPath.addCircle(mCenterX, mCenterY, mRevealRadius, Path.Direction.CW);
                final int state = canvas.save();
                canvas.clipPath(mRevealPath);
                boolean isInvalidate = super.drawChild(canvas, child, drawTime);
                canvas.restoreToCount(state);
                return isInvalidate;
            }
```

I add a LinearLayout with a TextView in it as a child to test.

Comment: is it hardware accelerated view?

Comment: Yes.I didn't set the layer type,it should be.Hardware accelerated view does not support the custom draw like this?

Comment: The hardware accelerate is the reason that I can't get a circle.Thank you.